# How to get grocery stores list as google showing in map

Tags: json, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API to get grocery stores list.

Query:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.715738,%20-117.161084&radius=12218&type=grocery_or_supermarket&key="GoogleAPIKey"

It is giving me some different data.

But I want list data like google provides in google map search as showing in attached screenshot: -

[image]

Is there any other way to get this list in json/xml format?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given URL gives me JSON Response only, may I know what exact bug, please do a recheck and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You use `type` for searching with the API, but when you are on the maps webpage you use plain text.

If you use this link you get almost the same results as on the webpage except for Food 4 Less

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.715738, -117.161084&radius=2000&keyword=Grocery store&key=`

Answer (score 0):

Using the API you posted i was able to get a result that looks like what google explained in the documentation https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search, if you can update your question by adding the response you are getting, maybe it will be easy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion guys.
I have resolved my query by using **textsearch** google api as mentioned below: -

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=""&radius=12218&type=grocery&key="GoogleAPIKey"

Thanks.